# Pip installation problem, the computer itself creates a folder and uploads a new pip there

Tags: python, pip

There is a problem with updating pip.

After installing python, I decided to upgrade pip to the newest version, and after I entered `pip install --upgrade --user pip`, the updated pip was installed in an auto-generated folder in roaming, I did not create this folder.

What should I do here?

[Video with problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ajl71uCHjv0&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=%D0%AA%D0%B5%D0%AA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you gave the option `--user` to pip. That option means to install the files in a user specific directory, so that they will not affect other users environment (when both users have installed pip version 20, and user1 upgrades to 21, user2 still uses 20). To fix this, either remove --user option, and install globally, or add the new directory to your PATH as pip suggests.

Comment: I started doing what you said, and now cmd is writing to me "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable.
ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install". What should I do here?

Comment: @Sycylia you obviously removed the module name too. Try this (you have to enter your administrator password, pip will then get installed globally for all users) : `runas /user:Administrator pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Thank you so much, I am very grateful to you, it helped

Comment: @Sycylia if my answer helped you, accept it please by clicking the grey checkmark on the left of it